# При переносе данных в csv символы с диакритикой видоизменяются

Tags: python, csv

Слова на французском я беру из файла txt, далее работаю с ними и вместе с другими получившимися данными заливаю в csv файл. При прямом выводе (print) слова написаны корректно, однако в итоговом csv-файле буквы с аксанами заменяются на другие символы (Néogène - NГ©ogГЁne). Это можно как-то исправить? Заранее спасибо за ответ!

```
dict_sample = {
        "Word": word,
        "Fr-ru": fr_ru,
        "En.wiktionary": gram_cat_wiki,
        "Larousse.fr": gram_cat_larousse,
        "Match_wiktionary": match_wiki,
        "Match_larousse": match_larousse  
    }
    
    print(f'{word} {fr_ru} {gram_cat_wiki} {gram_cat_larousse} {match_wiki} {match_larousse}')
    data = data.append(dict_sample)
    return data

# создаем таблицу csv и сливаем туда данные

def data_to_csv(data):
    field_names = ["Word", "Fr-ru", "En.wiktionary", "Larousse.fr", "Match_wiktionary", "Match_larousse"]
    with open('Final_fr_1.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = field_names)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open()` в windows по умолчанию открывает файл для записи в windows-1251, поэтому указывайте прямо:

```
 with open('Final_fr_1.csv', mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
```

Comment: Мне кажется надо сначала узнать в какой кодировке файл txt, может он в западноевропейской?

Comment: Добавление кодировки ситуацию, к сожалению, не исправило. Информация о txt-файле: {'encoding': 'utf-8', 'confidence': 0.99, 'language': ''}

Comment: @АлёнаМуравьева, а чем потом csv просматриваете?

Comment: Файл, вероятно, записан правильно - в кодировке utf-8, а вот просматриваете вы его каким-то средством, которое показывает в кодировке 1251.

Comment: Открыла в Notepad, теперь все отлично! Спасибо за помощь